# Getting pagination to work with React Komposer

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, pagination

I'm using Meteor 1.3.4.1, kurounin:pagination 1.0.9, and react-komposer 1.8.0 (npm package).

So here's my code for instantiating the pagination within composer function:

```
function composer(props, onData) {
  console.log('loading pages');
  const pagination = new Meteor.Pagination(UfcFighters);

  if( pagination.ready() ) {
    console.log('ready');
    const fighters = {
      columns: [
        { width: '5%', label: '', className: '' },
        { width: '20%', label: 'Name', className: 'text-center' },
        { width: '20%', label: 'Wins/Losses/Draws', className: 'text-center' },
        { width: '20%', label: 'Weight Class', className: 'text-center' },
        { width: '10%', label: 'Status', className: 'text-center' },
        { width: '10%', label: 'Rank', className: 'text-center' },
      ],
      data: pagination.getPage(),
    };
    onData(null, { fighters, pagination });
  }
};
```

Is this the proper use for React Komposer? I noticed that the Pagination would constantly load the subscription and never be ready to present the data. The console output would say 'loading pages' repeatedly, but it never says 'ready'.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer via the project maintainer of [kurounin:pagination](https://github.com/Kurounin/Pagination) and here's my updated code which is confirmed to work with react komposer:

```
const pagination = new Meteor.Pagination(UfcFighters, {
  sort: { id: 1 }
});

function composer(props, onData) {
  const fighterDocs = pagination.getPage();

  if( pagination.ready() ) {
    const fighters = {
      columns: [
        { width: '5%', label: '', className: '' },
        { width: '20%', label: 'Name', className: 'text-center' },
        { width: '20%', label: 'Wins/Losses/Draws', className: 'text-center' },
        { width: '20%', label: 'Weight Class', className: 'text-center' },
        { width: '10%', label: 'Status', className: 'text-center' },
        { width: '10%', label: 'Rank', className: 'text-center' },
      ],
      data: fighterDocs,
    };
    onData(null, { fighters, pagination });
  }
};

export default composeWithTracker(composer)(FightersList);
```

I moved the pagination instance to outside of the composer function because it was constantly instantiating new Paginations and bogging down the app. Now it's running smoothly.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good to me, I think you just need to return if the pagination is not ready.

```
function composer(props, onData) {
  const pagination = new Meteor.Pagination(UfcFighters);
  if(!pagination.ready()) { return; }
  const fighters = {
    columns: [
      { width: '5%', label: '', className: '' },
      { width: '20%', label: 'Name', className: 'text-center' },
      { width: '20%', label: 'Wins/Losses/Draws', className: 'text-center' },
      { width: '20%', label: 'Weight Class', className: 'text-center' },
      { width: '10%', label: 'Status', className: 'text-center' },
      { width: '10%', label: 'Rank', className: 'text-center' },
    ],
    data: pagination.getPage(),
  };
  onData(null, { fighters, pagination });
};
```

Comment: What's the null stand for in that `onData` call?